# Symfony 3 - Form collection field error displaying outside the field

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

Could anyone tell me why error related to form collection is displaying outside the particular field and how to move it to place like you see in image included below?

[image]

Code of this field:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Valid
 * @ORM\OneToMany(
 *     targetEntity="PageFile",
 *     mappedBy="page",
 *     cascade={"persist","remove"},
 *     orphanRemoval=true
 * )
 * @var PageFile[]
 * @Assert\Count(max="1")
 */
private $pageFiles;
```

Config:

```
                - property: 'pageFiles'
                  type: 'collection'
                  type_options:
                      entry_type: 'Notimeo\PageBundle\Form\Type\MyFileType'
                      by_reference: false
                      error_bubbling: false
```

I'm using [EasyAdminBundle](https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle) and here's my whole project: https://github.com/ktrzos/SymfonyBasic. Problem applies to "*Notimeo\PageBundle*".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see other errors are places above the input fields, so unless this is somehow positioned using CSS (which is very unlikely) it looks like the error is related to the form itself and not the input field. That's the same type of error like invalid CSRF token for example.

Your issue is probably related to [Form Collection error bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621368/form-collection-error-bubbling) where poster asks basically the same question as you.

The recommendation is to set:

```
cascade_validation' => true
```

Or, if you are using Symfony 3:

```
error_bubbling  => false
```

Comment: `The option "cascade_validation" does not exist.`

Comment: And I see, that poster is using Symfony 2.1. Here I'm using Symfony 3.0.1. It can make a difference.

Comment: It looks like it's been removed in Symfony3, I don't know what version you're using. See Symfony 2.8 doc:  http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/form.html#cascade-validation. They recommend using Valid constraint instead http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Valid.html

Comment: As You can see, I'm using it on this property (code above) ;).

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos `error_bubbling` seems to be still present in Symfony 3.0. Are you sure it doesn't work for you? Because it's just the option you need in this case.

Comment: @JavierEguiluz Yup, tried `error_bubbling: false` also (edited question). Not working :(.

Comment: Here's my whole project: https://github.com/ktrzos/SymfonyBasic. Problem applies to "Notimeo\PageBundle".

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos I've added the `@Assert\Count(max="1")` to the EasyAdmin Demo app and I can't reproduce the error. The `error_bubbling` option is working as expected. See http://imgur.com/w0dJw6A

Comment: @JavierEguiluz *<facepalm>* I've added this option to the wrong field. It's working now. Thanks!